# Pass data to the Container View in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, uicontainerview

I'm using a table view & a Container view in my VC. Now i want to send the selected indexPath.row to my Container View. I tried to achieve this with the help of Prepareforsegue. But it is not working.

I think that both the table view & the Container view loads simultaneously. So that the data is not passed. Please correct me if i am wrong.

I need to achieve the below Layout.

If a Movie is selected from the table cell then the Video has to be Played in the Player.

Thanks in Advance!

[image: Current UI]

**VC**           `PlayerController is the Container view`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var PlayerScene = segue.destinationViewController as! PlayerController

        if let indexPath = self.LessonTable.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let selectedLesson = LessonArray[indexPath.row]
            PlayerScene.selectedDir = Dir[indexPath.row]
            println(Dir[indexPath.row])
            PlayerScene.selectedPath = Path[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
```

**PlayerController**

```
class PlayerController: AVPlayerViewController {


    var selectedDir :String!
    var selectedPath :String!
    var url:NSURL?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

url  = NSURL(string: "http://www.wine.com/\(selectedDir!)/android/high/\(selectedPath!)")!

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.play()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Three** ways to pass selected **index or info** from one class to another class

1. **Properties** :- Create a property in PlayerController for selected indexPath & then assign that property using PlayerScene object in prepareForSegue method.
2. **Notification** :- You can pass dictionary with NSNotificationCenter and get that dictionary in NSNotificationCenter handler method.
3. **Method calling** :- Create method in PlayerController class and call that method using PlayerScene object in prepareForSegue method.

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, you should use `NSNotificationCenter` because you will require to send data multiple times to your PlayerController.

**Class A (PlayerController.h)**

```
 //Add Observer in init method
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handler:", name: "MyNotification", object: nil)

//Handler
func handler(notif: NSNotification) {
    println("MyNotification was handled");
    println("userInfo: \(notif.userInfo)");
    println("SelectedCellIndex \(notif.userInfo!["selectedCellIndex"])"); //Validate userInfo here. it could be nil

}
```

**Class B**

```
// Call from any method
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MyNotification", object: nil, userInfo: ["selectedCellIndex" : indexPath.row]); // sender data in userInfo as per your requirements
```